# Subversion Copy Hook on Windows

Tags: svn, windows-xp, svn-hooks

I am working on a web based project in my free time. I have SVN set up on my machine (running XP). What I would like to do is have a copy of my repository copied to the htdocs folder (Dev machine) post-commit via a hook. That way I can test my changes in a browser.

I know that I can write up a .bat file, but I'm not sure what the syntax would be. I can do a basic DOS Copy command, but I saw one example that provided a username and password to SVN at copy time. Do I need to do this?

Can someone point me in the right direction as far a syntax for the .bat file?

Or maybe even suggest a better method.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you pointing the Web-Server configuration in that way to use your working copy as the htdocs folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [red-bean book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/svn-book.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1) has a section on hooks.  The [post-commit parameters](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) are described also.

```
@echo off
set destination=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah\blah
set source_path=%1
set revision=%2
svn export --username user --password pass "%source_path%" "%destination%"
```

That all being said; I wouldn't couple your testing environment so tightly with your source control if you didn't have to.

You could write a completely standalone job that polls the subversion location you're interested in and does the export when it detects a change.

Comment: +1, but you should remove the spaces around the '=' sign, or they become part of the variable name. Also, wrap their usage with quotes in case the path contains spaces, e.g. `"%source_path%"`